# how to Find elements dynamically with too many hierarchy using cypress

Tags: cypress

```js
<div role="application" aria-label="Calendar" class="dayPicker dayPicker--inline dayPicker--horizontal dayPicker--withBorder dayPicker--focusedStartDate" style="width: 619px;"><div><div class="" style="width: 618px;"><div class="dayPicker__weekHeaders dayPicker__weekHeaders--horizontal" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><div class="dayPicker__weekHeader dayPicker__weekHeader--double" style="left: 14px;"><ul class="weekHeader__container"><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Mo</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Tu</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>We</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Th</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Fr</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Sa</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Su</small></li></ul></div><div class="dayPicker__weekHeader dayPicker__weekHeader--double" style="left: 314px;"><ul class="weekHeader__container"><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Mo</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Tu</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>We</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Th</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Fr</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Sa</small></li><li class="weekHeader__list" style="width: 39px;"><small>Su</small></li></ul></div></div><div class="dayPicker__focusRegion" role="region" tabindex="-1"><div class="dayPickerNavigation dayPickerNavigation--horizontal"><div role="button" tabindex="0" class="dayPickerNavigation_button dayPickerNavigation__button--default dayPickerNavigation__button--disabled dayPickerNavigation__button--horizontalDefault dayPickerNavigation__leftButton--horizontalDefault" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="Move backward to switch to the previous month."><div class="prev-month"></div></div><div role="button" tabindex="0" class="dayPickerNavigation__button dayPickerNavigation__button--default dayPickerNavigation__button--horizontalDefault dayPickerNavigation__rightButton--horizontalDefault" aria-label="Move forward to switch to the next month."><div class="next-month"></div></div></div><div class="dayPicker__transitionContainer dayPicker__transitionContainer--horizontal" style="width: 618px; height: 327px;"><div class="calendarMonthGrid calendarMonthGrid--horizontal calendarMonthGrid--double" style="transform: translateX(0px); width: 1200px;"><div class="calendarMonthGrid__month--horizontal calendarMonthGrid__month--hideForAnimation calendarMonthGrid__month--hidden"><div class="calendarMonth" data-visible="false" style="padding: 0px 13px;"><div class="calendarMonth__caption"><span>August 2022</span></div><div class="calendarMonth__container"><table class="calendarMonth__table" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Monday, August 1, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">1</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Tuesday, August 2, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">2</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Wednesday, August 3, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">3</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Thursday, August 4, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">4</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Friday, August 5, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">5</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Saturday, August 6, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">6</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Sunday, August 7, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">7</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Monday, August 8, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">8</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Tuesday, August 9, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">9</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Wednesday, August 10, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">10</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Thursday, August 11, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">11</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Friday, August 12, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">12</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Saturday, August 13, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">13</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Sunday, August 14, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">14</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Monday, August 15, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">15</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Tuesday, August 16, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">16</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Wednesday, August 17, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">17</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Thursday, August 18, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">18</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Friday, August 19, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">19</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Saturday, August 20, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">20</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Sunday, August 21, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">21</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Monday, August 22, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">22</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Tuesday, August 23, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">23</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Wednesday, August 24, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">24</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Thursday, August 25, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">25</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Friday, August 26, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">26</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Saturday, August 27, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">27</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Sunday, August 28, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">28</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Monday, August 29, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">29</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Tuesday, August 30, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">30</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Wednesday, August 31, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">31</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div class="calendarMonthGrid__month--horizontal"><div class="calendarMonth" data-visible="true" style="padding: 0px 13px;"><div class="calendarMonth__caption"><span>September 2022</span></div><div class="calendarMonth__container"><table class="calendarMonth__table" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Thursday, September 1, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">1</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Friday, September 2, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">2</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Saturday, September 3, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">3</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Sunday, September 4, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">4</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Monday, September 5, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">5</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--defaultCursor calendarDay--blockedOutsideRange" role="button" aria-label="Not available. Tuesday, September 6, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">6</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--today" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, September 7, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">7</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, September 8, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">8</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, September 9, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">9</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, September 10, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">10</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, September 11, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">11</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, September 12, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">12</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, September 13, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">13</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, September 14, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">14</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, September 15, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">15</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, September 16, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">16</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selected calendarDay--selectedSpan calendarDay--selectedStart" role="button" aria-label="Selected as start date. Saturday, September 17, 2022" tabindex="0" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">17</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, September 18, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">18</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, September 19, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">19</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, September 20, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">20</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, September 21, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">21</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, September 22, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">22</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, September 23, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">23</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, September 24, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">24</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, September 25, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">25</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, September 26, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">26</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, September 27, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">27</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, September 28, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">28</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selectedSpan calendarDay--lastInRange" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, September 29, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">29</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--selected calendarDay--selectedEnd" role="button" aria-label="Selected as end date. Friday, September 30, 2022" tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">30</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div class="calendarMonthGrid__month--horizontal"><div class="calendarMonth" data-visible="true" style="padding: 0px 13px;"><div class="calendarMonth__caption"><span>October 2022</span></div><div class="calendarMonth__container"><table class="calendarMonth__table" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, October 1, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">1</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, October 2, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">2</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, October 3, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">3</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, October 4, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">4</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, October 5, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">5</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, October 6, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">6</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, October 7, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">7</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, October 8, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">8</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, October 9, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">9</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, October 10, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">10</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, October 11, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">11</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, October 12, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">12</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, October 13, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">13</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, October 14, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">14</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, October 15, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">15</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, October 16, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">16</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, October 17, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">17</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, October 18, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">18</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, October 19, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">19</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, October 20, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">20</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, October 21, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">21</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, October 22, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">22</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, October 23, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">23</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, October 24, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">24</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, October 25, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">25</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, October 26, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">26</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Thursday, October 27, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">27</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Friday, October 28, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">28</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme" role="button" aria-label="Choose Saturday, October 29, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">29</td><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--lastDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Sunday, October 30, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">30</td></tr><tr><td class="calendarDay calendarDay--default calendarDay--defaultTheme calendarDay--firstDayOfWeek" role="button" aria-label="Choose Monday, October 31, 2022 as your check-in date. It’s available." tabindex="-1" style="width: 39px; height: 38px;">31</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div class="calendarMonthGrid__month--horizontal calendarMonthGrid__month--hidden"><div class="calendarMonth" data-visible="false" style="padding: 0px 13px;"><div class="calendarMonth__caption">
```

This is what I get when I simply find my element
cy.xpath("//*[@id='globalSearch']//div[@aria-label='Calendar']//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]//div//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]")

how can i reduce too many static divs[] ?

Comment: The question lacks enough detail to resolve - please provide an idea of the HTML page you are trying to query.

Comment: Sorry its too big, i cant paste it here

Answer (score 0):

If there is text you can use to limit your search, then you can use `.contains()`.

```js
cy.contains('.your-selector', 'text')
```

or regex text

```js
cy.contains('.your-selector', /text/)
```

Comment: I have to go untill i find the <td> and before that there are lost of parent / child div tags

Comment: its calendar basically, i need to find the date, and it doesn't have any text to use contains

Comment: This is the original hierarchy - i still have get rid of most of the extra divs - [@id="globalSearch"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]

Comment: Do you have to go thru the calendar to enter a date?

Comment: i have to go through the calendar, so it opens 4 containers <div tags> those are 3 months sept to nov. each of this months containers has their own <tbody><tr><td>. so it will find 3 <tbody> at global search. but as soon as we go inside i cant use <tbody>[2]

Comment: i cant paste the html its too big

Comment: This would have been good to share in the question post itself.

Comment: ok how can I paste it in <html> format in the original query ?

Comment: Edit your post and checkout formatting options.

Comment: Please see the post, i have tried to put it there, since it was too many char, i had to remove some code from end...but hopefully it should give an overall idea

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can see (not using xpath)

```js
cy.get('[@aria-label="Calendar"]') 
  .find('tbody tr:eq(3) td:eq(1)')
```

Comment: This doesn't work - this gives me first <tbody> tag and that's selecting dates from August which is not selectable as of today. i want to select dates from current month and so i have to get <tbody(2)> that is what i cant find directly. its using different <div> then the first <tbody>

Comment: is there any function or custom command can be used to select any dates from the calendar, that will also check the current month and omit the previous months

Comment: If you want a specific tbody just use `tbody:eq(2)` - same as for tr and td.

Comment: tried .find('tbody:eq(2) tr:eq(3) td:eq(4)') and it didnt work

Comment: i have to go through the calendar, so it opens 4 containers <div tags> those are 3 months sept to nov. each of this months containers has their own <tbody><tr><td>. so it will find 3 <tbody> at global search. but as soon as we go inside to select date for a particular month it wont find tbody[2] or tbady[3] etc